# why does the wxPanel constructor have a default WindowID but the wxBookCtrl constructor doesn't?

Tags: wxwidgets

Do you know why the wxPanel constructor have a default WindowID but the wxBookCtrl default constructor requires an explicit WindowID? I mean it's not consistent the way you create a control object in wxWidgets. For example

```
wxPanel* panel  = new wxPanel(parent)
```

but

```
wxBookCtrl* book = new wxBookCtrl(parent, wxID_ANY)
```

Are there any advantages to or requirents of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is still somewhat consistent in the sense that writing `new wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY)` works too, but `wxPanel` is an exception in allowing to omit `wxID_ANY` entirely. This is due to the fact that you basically never want to bind to the events of the panel by its ID, so you never care about its value, while it's more useful for the other controls, including `wxBookCtrl`.